# Result of calculating precision and recall and related seem odd

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm simulating a search engine which retrieves 10 documents, but only 5 of them are relevant.

```
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import average_precision_score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from sklearn.metrics.ranking import _binary_clf_curve

y_true = np.array([True, True, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, True])
```

Decreasing threshold to get more documents:

```
y_scores = np.array([1, .9, .8, .7, .6, .5, .4, .3, .2, .1])
```

Now getting precisions, recalls and thresholds:

```
precisions, recalls, thresholds1 = precision_recall_curve(y_true, y_scores)

print("\nPresicions:")
for pr in precisions:
    print('{0:0.2f}'.format(pr), end='; ')

print("\nRecalls:")
for rec in recalls:
    print('{0:0.2f}'.format(rec), end='; ')

print("\nThresholds:")
for thr in thresholds1:
    print('{0:0.2f}'.format(thr), end='; ')
```

Output 1

```
Presicions:
0.50; 0.44; 0.50; 0.57; 0.67; 0.60; 0.75; 0.67; 1.00; 1.00; 1.00;
Recalls:
1.00; 0.80; 0.80; 0.80; 0.80; 0.60; 0.60; 0.40; 0.40; 0.20; 0.00;
Thresholds:
0.10; 0.20; 0.30; 0.40; 0.50; 0.60; 0.70; 0.80; 0.90; 1.00;
```

Output code for case 2:

```
falsePositiveRates, truePositiveRates, thresholds2 = roc_curve(y_true, y_scores, pos_label = True)

print("\nFPRs:")
for fpr in falsePositiveRates:
    print('{0:0.2f}'.format(fpr), end='; ')

print("\nTPRs:")
for tpr in truePositiveRates:
    print('{0:0.2f}'.format(tpr), end='; ')

print("\nThresholds:")
for thr in thresholds2:
    print('{0:0.2f}'.format(thr), end='; ')
```

Output 2

```
FPRs:
0.00; 0.00; 0.20; 0.20; 0.40; 0.40; 1.00; 1.00;
TPRs:
0.20; 0.40; 0.40; 0.60; 0.60; 0.80; 0.80; 1.00;
Thresholds:
1.00; 0.90; 0.80; 0.70; 0.60; 0.50; 0.20; 0.10;
```

Questions
In output 1, why is the last precision (which will be the 1st on plot) computed as 1 instead of 0?

In output 2, why are the lengths of of FPR, TPR, and Threshold 8 instead of 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In output1 why the last precision (which will be the 1st on plot) is set to 1 instead of 0?

At the most restrictive threshold, you select only one item, which is relevant (true positive).

> In output2 why counts of FPR, TPR, Threshold are 8 instead of 10

You allowed drop_intermediate to default to `True`.  0.3 and 0.4 are sub-optimal thresholds.

Comment: but I expected to 10 precisions/recalls, but here I have 11.

Comment: That's the infamous "fence-post" problem.  You have 10 thresholds.  Each is a divider, a partition point.  10 division points provide 11 regions.  Remember that you have an open-ended region on each end.

Comment: I changed the first True to False, but anyway got the last precision = 1
0.40; 0.33; 0.38; 0.43; 0.50; 0.40; 0.50; 0.33; 0.50; 0.00; 1.00;
May it be any default value which is always = 1?

Comment: That could be.  I can't test this myself, as I have an incompatible set-up here.